# Pulling name value pair from a structured adsense code block contained in a txt file

Tags: php, regex

I have a txt file which contains a google adsense code block and I'm trying to pull in the file via file_get_contents to extract the values of the google_ad_client and google_ad_slot variables.

In the examples below, I want to return to my calling function:

```
$google_ad_client = 'pub-1234567890987654';
$google_ad_slot = '1234567890'
```

The file may contain one of either of these two formats and I wont know which the user has chosen:

Newer Ad Unit Style

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-1234567890987654";
google_ad_slot = "1234567890";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-google-script"></script>
```

Classic Style

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-1234567890987654";
/* 336x280, created 8/6/09 */
google_ad_slot = "1234567890";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
google_ad_format="336x280_as";
google_ad_type="text_image";
google_color_border="FFFFFF";
google_color_bg="FFFFFF";
google_color_link="2200CC";
google_color_url="000000";
google_color_text="777777";
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$code = <<<STR
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-1234567890987654";
google_ad_slot = "1234567890";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-google-script"></script>
STR;

if (preg_match('/google_ad_client = "([^"]+)";/', $code, $m)) {
    $google_ad_client = $m[1];
}
if (preg_match('/google_ad_slot = "([^"]+)";/', $code, $m)) {
    $google_ad_slot = $m[1];
}

var_dump($google_ad_client, $google_ad_slot);
```

.
And you'll get as output :

```
string 'pub-1234567890987654' (length=20)
string '1234567890' (length=10)
```

*(Tested with the second portion of code, and seems to work OK too)*

Just as a precaution, you might also want to change the regexes to something like this, so accept the same kind of code without any space *(or with any number of spaces)* :

```
if (preg_match('/google_ad_client\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*;/', $code, $m)) {
    $google_ad_client = $m[1];
}
if (preg_match('/google_ad_slot\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*;/', $code, $m)) {
    $google_ad_slot = $m[1];
}
```

And, just for fun, the same thing with only one regex, if you want to retrieve several pieces of informations :

```
$results = array();
if (preg_match_all('/(google_ad_client|google_ad_slot)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*;/', $code, $m)) {
    $count = count($m[1]);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i<$count ; $i++) {
        $results[$m[1][$i]] = $m[2][$i];
    }
}

// TODO : test is set (see isset) before using those
var_dump($results['google_ad_client'], $results['google_ad_slot']);
```

Which will give you the same output :

```
string 'pub-1234567890987654' (length=20)
string '1234567890' (length=10)
```

Comment: Man, you regex guys amaze me <big fat grin>. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data=file("file");
$d = preg_grep("/^google_ad_client|google_ad_slot/",$data);
print_r($d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function fun($page) {
        $result = array();
        if(preg_match('{google_ad_client\s*=\s*"(.*?)"}',$page,$matches)) {
                $result['google_ad_client'] = $matches[1];

        }
        if(preg_match('{google_ad_slot\s*=\s*"(.*?)"}',$page,$matches)) {
                $result['google_ad_slot'] = $matches[1];

        }     
        return $result;
}
```